# Lower Quartile, Median and Upper Quartile

Tags: probability, statistics, quantile

Hello I want to calculate the $Q_1$, $Q_2$ and $Q_3$ for my Cumulative Probability Function $F(x)=\dfrac{e^x}{1+e^x}$.

So if $P=\dfrac{e^x}{1+e^x}$ how do I convert this expression to the form $x=...$ step by step? I am really bad at convertig mathematical expression I would appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could start by rearranging $P=\dfrac{e^x}{1+e^x}$ to be $e^x=$ something with  $P$ but not $x$

Comment: so basically multiply the quation with $(1+e^x)$. That gives me $P+Pe^x=e^x$ thats how far i got so far..

Comment: "not $x$".  So the next step might be $e^x-Pe^x =P$ and then you might factor that so you can get $e^x$ on one side and something with $P$ but not $x$ on the other

Comment: ok now i have $e^x=\dfrac{P}{1-P}$ now the last step is to use the logarithmic function?

Comment: which would give me $x=ln(\dfrac{P}{1-P})$?

Comment: Indeed.  You end up with the so-called *[logit function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit)*

Comment: God bless you thanks for you supprt! :)